# Dynamic Changes based on search words

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api

This is a simple question I can't find a concrete answer to (with a working example).

I simply want to retrieve the keywords the visitor typed before clicking on my Adwords Ad.

Afterwords, I want make changes to the site based on this info (this part I can handle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access the exact search term that linked to an ad impression with AdWords click data. But you can access the keyword and pass it as an URL parameter with Adwords click.
e.g. you can use a ValueTrack parameter in your final URL, such as example.com/blueshoes?kwd={keyword}. If your ad was shown on the results page for `buy blue shoes` and was triggered by your phrase match keyword `"blue shoes"` the page URL will be example.com/blueshoes?kwd=blue%20shoes

Check the [AdWords docs](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305348?co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dfalse&hl=en) for more details